# Request fails on the second attempt

Tags: node.js, express, telegram-bot, telegraf

I have an app that send `POST` request and wait for certain amount of time until it gets message back from telegram bot API, I'm using [Telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org/) library to interact with telegram bot API. it works fine on the first request but i get `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` error without even sending anything back to the server for second time. here's what the code looks like...

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const bot = require("./config/bot");

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    // if it doesn't get message back within 5min it'll close the request
    req.setTimeout(300000);

    bot.command("start", (ctx) => {
        let text = ctx.message.text;
        res.send(text);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: This error generally happens when there is no return for res.send(). Try `return res.send(text);`